# Is there a faster way to convert a hexadecimal fractional part to a decimal one?

Tags: java, algorithm, hex, radix

I wrote a program that generates digits of pi in hexadecimal. Every so often, at benchmark values, I would like to convert the hexadecimal value I have into a decimal one and save it to a file. Currently I am using BigDecimal to do that math with this code:

```
private static String toDecimal(String hex) {
    String rawHex = hex.replace(".", "");
    BigDecimal base = new BigDecimal(new BigInteger(rawHex, 16));
    BigDecimal factor = new BigDecimal(BigInteger.valueOf(16).pow(rawHex.length() - 1));
    BigDecimal value = base.divide(factor);
    return value.toPlainString().substring(0, hex.length());
}
```

Note that this method will only work for hexadecimal values with one digit in the integral part, pi included, do not copy and paste this for general use.

So this code works fine, but for the latest benchmark, 2.5m digits, the conversion took 11.3 hours to complete.

Is there any faster way to do this manually?

I tried dividing the first decimal place by 16, the second by 16^2, etc but this would quickly get out of hand. Maybe some way of bitshifting the digits back to keep the divisor low? But potentially the n+1, n+2, n+3, etc digits need to be processed to get the correct value for n.

Comment: Try using bigger blocks. Treat it like it's base 16^2 or 16^3 or 16^4 or 16^k.

Comment: Base conversion is equivalent to divmod for non-trivial cases. The special case mod calculations for B = b+1 don't help much. A good place to check handling of large numbers is GMP: the [GNU Multiple Precision
Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/manual/Binary-to-Radix.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I believe your function `toDecimal` is wrong as it doesn't correctly convert input `".1a"` (it's off by a factor of 16), for example, and throws an exception for input `".800"`. The third line should be:

```
BigDecimal factor = new BigDecimal(BigInteger.valueOf(16).pow(rawHex.length()));
```

The exception arises from:

```
return value.toPlainString().substring(0, hex.length());
```

The converted value could be shorter than the input value and you get a `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Moving on:

**In truth I have not benchmarked this against your current method; I just offer this as "food for thought." Here I am doing the multiplications as a child is taught to do it in school and in your case we have a large loop just to produce one digit. But if you could somehow adapt this to use BigDecimal (it's not clear how you would) it might be quicker than your current approach (what's really needed is a BigHexadecimal class).**

It can be observed that converting a fraction from one base to another can be done using multiplications. In this case we have the following hexadecimal fraction (we can ignore the integer portion, which is 3 when converting pi):

**.h<sub>1</sub>h<sub>2</sub>h<sub>3</sub>h<sub>4</sub> ... h<sub>n</sub>**

where **h<sub>n</sub>** is the n<sup>th</sup> hexadecimal "nibble".

We wish to convert the above to the following decimal fraction:

**.d<sub>1</sub>d<sub>2</sub>d<sub>3</sub>d<sub>4</sub> ... d<sub>n</sub>**

where **d<sub>n</sub>** is the n<sup>th</sup> decimal digit.

If we were to multiply both quantities by 10, we would get:

**h<sup>'</sup><sub>1</sub>.h<sup>'</sup><sub>2</sub>h<sup>'</sup><sub>3</sub>h<sup>'</sup><sub>4</sub> ... h<sup>'</sup><sub>n</sub>**

The primes (<sup>`</sup>) denote that we have completely new hexadecimal nibble values following the multiplication.

and

**d<sub>1</sub>.d<sub>2</sub>d<sub>3</sub>d<sub>4</sub> ... d<sub>n</sub>**

The multiplication by 10 just shifts the decimal fraction one place to the left.

We must note that the quantities to the left of the decimal point must be equal, i.e. **d<sub>1</sub>** == **h<sup>'</sup><sub>1</sub>**. Thus we repeatedly multiply our hexadecimal fraction by 10 and each time we do we take the integer portion as the next decimal digit for our conversion. We repeat this until either our new hexadecimal fraction becomes 0 or some arbitrary number of decimal digits have been produced:

[See Java Demo](https://ideone.com/LpPu0c)

```
class Test {

    private static String toDecimal(String hex, int numberDigits) {
        /* converts a string such as "13.1a" in base 16 to "19.1015625" in base 10 */
        int index = hex.indexOf('.');
        assert index != -1;
        StringBuilder decimal = new StringBuilder((index == 0) ? "" : String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(0, index), 16)));
        decimal.append('.');
        int l = hex.length() - index - 1;
        assert l >= 1;
        int firstIndex = index + 1;
        int hexDigits[] = new int[l];
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            hexDigits[i] = Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(i + firstIndex, i + firstIndex + 1), 16);
        }
        while (numberDigits != 0 && l != 0) {
            int carry = 0;
            boolean allZeroes = true;
            for (int i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                int value = hexDigits[i] * 10 + carry;
                if (value == 0 && allZeroes) {
                    l = i;
                }
                else {
                    allZeroes = false;
                    carry = (int)(value / 16);
                    hexDigits[i] = value % 16;
                }
            }
            numberDigits--;
            if (carry != 0 || (numberDigits != 0 && l != 0))
                decimal.append("0123456789".charAt(carry));
        }
        return decimal.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(toDecimal("13.1a", 15));
        System.out.println(toDecimal("13.8", 15));
        System.out.println(toDecimal("13.1234", 15));
    }

}
```

Prints:

```
19.1015625
19.5
19.07110595703125
```

Comment: The method I included must be used with values that have exactly one integral decimal place, which works for my pi application, for example 0.1a and 0.800 would work. But you are right about the exception, I am now padding zeros to fit the length if it is not long enough.

I played around with your method and it produces the wrong digits starting after 30 places, for an input of 100k digits. However, I noticed that BigDecimal produces the wrong digits starting after 2735 for 100k digits. I might need to rethink this whole thing, is my hex wrong or the conversion. I'll come back to this.

Comment: I was able to verify my hex up to 8336 digits from here: https://gist.github.com/retrohacker/e5fff72b7b75ee058924
so it seems like it is generating them correctly. Here is my data if anyone would like to attempt to convert it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zcg1qDWvy4XqPFnWd-y1muH3FuHu2AAx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If your input has an integer to the left of the decimal point (as I know yours does, i.e. `3`), it's a very simple matter to modify the function to account for that and bypass it.

Comment: Yes yes, I was just saying that's why you were getting invalid values.

Comment: So with 100 hex digits, it was able to convert it to 100 decimal digits perfectly, same with 250, 500, 1000, 2500. But for any amount over that, it diverges from the correct value at the 2732nd decimal digit. This must be a flaw in BigDecimal, so a correct conversion must be possible but I am beginning to think it would be slower rather than faster.

Comment: @ZGorlock `100 hex digits, it was able to convert it to 100 decimal digits perfectly` - that's disproportionate, should be 120 decimal digits, at least.

Comment: @greybeard I am taking the first 100 digits in the decimal number that was created, it may just be luck that the final digits in that 100 are correct, but with 20 extra decimal places, the chance that a value will carry all the way back to the 100th place is very unlikely.

Comment: Actually for 100 hex digits, the resulting decimal is 502 digits long. You can see the full code here by the way: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ZGorlock/Java-Sandbox/master/PiBot/src/PiBot.java

Comment: I updated the `toDecimal` function because I wasn't 100% sure about a test I was making being correct in every circumstance.For what it's worth,  I think it's more robust now.

Comment: `toDecimal` now accepts input such as `"3.14159..."`., i.e. with hex digits to the left of the decimal point.

Comment: @Booboo Good improvement! It now produces exactly the same value as BigDecimal and takes about 1/5th the time at least for my tests with 25k and 100k digits. However, it also diverges from the correct value at the exact same place as BigDecimal. At the digit at place 2736 it produces a 6 when it should be a 5, and then from then on it is incorrect. I have verified my hex values up to 25k digits with other sources. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: https://ibb.co/vsVt05y First line is the correct value of pi, second is the BigDecimal result, third is your result.

Comment: Quite a coincidence that the algorithm I use and yours using BigDecimal diverge at the same exact place and in the same way, especially since the two methods have nothing in common. Makes one possibly suspect either that (1)  what you are comparing these results with might either be wrong (not likely) or (2) what you are starting out with as far as hexadecimal values is not quite correct, i.e. "garbage in, garbage out (no offense meant, but a more likely scenario). Thoughts? Try to follow the unassailable logic behind my approach. Other than bugs that might remain in the code, it should work.

Comment: You are right, comparing my data to the output from the world record holder, my values are off by one every couple hundred digits started at 2271. I will figure out what is causing that. Thank you very much for your conversion code, I will award you the bounty.

Comment: ("coincidentally", 2271 × log(16) is 2735)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @Booboo for the solution to this problem. I improved on his code a little so it should work in every case. I wanted to post it here for future visitors.

```
/**
 * Converts a hex number string to a decimal number string.
 *
 * @param hex      The hex number string.
 * @param accuracy The number of decimal places to return in the decimal number string.
 * @return The decimal number string.
 */
public static String hexToDecimal(String hex, int accuracy) {
    if (!hex.matches("[0-9A-Fa-f.\\-]+") || (accuracy < 0)) {
        return "";
    }
    
    boolean negative = hex.startsWith("-");
    hex = hex.replaceAll("^-", "");
    String integral = hex.contains(".") ? hex.substring(0, hex.indexOf(".")) : hex;
    String fraction = hex.contains(".") ? hex.substring(hex.indexOf(".") + 1) : "";
    if (integral.contains("-") || fraction.contains(".") || fraction.contains("-")) {
        return "";
    }
    
    StringBuilder decimal = new StringBuilder();
    decimal.append(negative ? "-" : "");
    decimal.append(integral.isEmpty() ? "0" : new BigDecimal(new BigInteger(integral, 16)).toPlainString());
    if (fraction.isEmpty() || (accuracy == 0)) {
        return decimal.toString();
    }
    decimal.append(".");
    
    int numberDigits = accuracy;
    int length = Math.min(fraction.length(), numberDigits);
    int[] hexDigits = new int[numberDigits];
    Arrays.fill(hexDigits, 0);
    IntStream.range(0, length).boxed().parallel().forEach(i -> hexDigits[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(fraction.charAt(i)), 16));
    
    while ((numberDigits != 0)) {
        int carry = 0;
        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int value = hexDigits[i] * 10 + carry;
            carry = value / 16;
            hexDigits[i] = value % 16;
        }
        decimal.append(carry);
        numberDigits--;
    }
    return decimal.toString();
}

/**
 * Converts a hex number string to a decimal number string.
 *
 * @param hex The hex number string.
 * @return The decimal number string.
 * @see #hexToDecimal(String, int)
 */
public static String hexToDecimal(String hex) {
    String fraction = hex.contains(".") ? hex.substring(hex.indexOf(".") + 1) : "";
    return hexToDecimal(hex, fraction.length());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //integer
    Assert.assertEquals("0", hexToDecimal("0"));
    Assert.assertEquals("1", hexToDecimal("1"));
    Assert.assertEquals("9", hexToDecimal("9"));
    Assert.assertEquals("15", hexToDecimal("F"));
    Assert.assertEquals("242", hexToDecimal("F2"));
    Assert.assertEquals("33190", hexToDecimal("81A6"));
    Assert.assertEquals("256", hexToDecimal("100"));
    Assert.assertEquals("1048576", hexToDecimal("100000"));
    Assert.assertEquals("5191557193152165532727847676938654", hexToDecimal("FFF6AA0322BC458D5D11A632099E"));
    Assert.assertEquals("282886881332428154466487121231991859970997056152877088222", hexToDecimal("B897A12C89896321C454A7DD9E150233CBB87A9F0233DDE"));
    Assert.assertEquals("-256", hexToDecimal("-100"));
    Assert.assertEquals("-144147542", hexToDecimal("-8978456"));
    Assert.assertEquals("-332651442596728389665499138728075237402", hexToDecimal("-FA42566214321CC67445D58EE874981A"));
    Assert.assertEquals("33190", hexToDecimal("81a6"));

    //decimal
    Assert.assertEquals("0.10", hexToDecimal("0.1a"));
    Assert.assertEquals("0.5", hexToDecimal("0.8"));
    Assert.assertEquals("0.0711", hexToDecimal("0.1234"));
    Assert.assertEquals("0.528966901", hexToDecimal("0.876A5FF4A"));
    Assert.assertEquals("-0.528966901", hexToDecimal("-0.876A5FF4A"));
    Assert.assertEquals("-0.00000000", hexToDecimal("-0.00000001"));
    Assert.assertEquals("-0.62067648792835838863907521427468", hexToDecimal("-0.9EE4A7810C666FF7453D06A44621030E"));
    Assert.assertEquals("0.528966901", hexToDecimal("0.876a5ff4a"));
    Assert.assertEquals("0.528966901", hexToDecimal(".876a5ff4a"));
    Assert.assertEquals("-0.528966901", hexToDecimal("-.876a5ff4a"));

    //combined
    Assert.assertEquals("15.33693", hexToDecimal("F.56412"));
    Assert.assertEquals("17220744.33934412", hexToDecimal("106C488.56DF41A2"));
    Assert.assertEquals("282886881332428154466487121231991859970997056152877088222.62067648792835838863907521427468", hexToDecimal("B897A12C89896321C454A7DD9E150233CBB87A9F0233DDE.9EE4A7810C666FF7453D06A44621030E"));
    Assert.assertEquals("-17220744.33934412", hexToDecimal("-106C488.56DF41A2"));
    Assert.assertEquals("-282886881332428154466487121231991859970997056152877088222.62067648792835838863907521427468", hexToDecimal("-B897A12C89896321C454A7DD9E150233CBB87A9F0233DDE.9EE4A7810C666FF7453D06A44621030E"));
    Assert.assertEquals("-17220744.33934412", hexToDecimal("-106c488.56df41a2"));
    Assert.assertEquals("3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808", hexToDecimal("3.243F6A8885A308D313198A2E03707344A4093822299F31D0082EFA98EC4E6C89452821E638D01377BE5466CF34E90C6CC0AC29B7C97"));

    //accuracy
    Assert.assertEquals("-0.00000", hexToDecimal("-0.00000001", 5));
    Assert.assertEquals("-0.000000000232830", hexToDecimal("-0.00000001", 15));
    Assert.assertEquals("-0", hexToDecimal("-0.00000001", 0));
    Assert.assertEquals("282886881332428154466487121231991859970997056152877088222.5", hexToDecimal("B897A12C89896321C454A7DD9E150233CBB87A9F0233DDE.9EE4A7810C666FF7453D06A44621030E", 1));
    Assert.assertEquals("3.14", hexToDecimal("3.243F6A8885A308D313198A2E03707344A4093822299F31D0082EFA98EC4E6C89452821E638D01377BE5466CF34E90C6CC0AC29B7C97", 2));
    Assert.assertEquals("3.1415926535", hexToDecimal("3.243F6A8885A308D313198A2E03707344A4093822299F31D0082EFA98EC4E6C89452821E638D01377BE5466CF34E90C6CC0AC29B7C97", 10));
    Assert.assertEquals("3.1415926535897932384626433", hexToDecimal("3.243F6A8885A308D313198A2E03707344A4093822299F31D0082EFA98EC4E6C89452821E638D01377BE5466CF34E90C6CC0AC29B7C97", 25));

    //invalid
    Assert.assertEquals("", hexToDecimal("0.00000.001"));
    Assert.assertEquals("", hexToDecimal("0.00000-001"));
    Assert.assertEquals("", hexToDecimal("156-081.00000001"));
    Assert.assertEquals("", hexToDecimal("hello"));
    Assert.assertEquals("", hexToDecimal("9g"));
    Assert.assertEquals("", hexToDecimal("9G"));
    Assert.assertEquals("", hexToDecimal("546.FDA", -1));
    Assert.assertEquals("", hexToDecimal("546.FDA", -999));
}
```